# Get rid of some output

Tags: python-3.x

```
#The program is as below.
```

The program allows user to try two times to guess two lottery numbers.
If user guesses i number correctly,user gets $100 and one more chance to play. If in the second chance the user guesses one number again, user gets nothing more.

```
import random 
guessed=False
attempts=2
while attempts > 0 and not guessed:
    lottery1= random.randint(0, 99)
    lottery2= random.randint(45,109)
    guess1 = int(input("Enter your first lottery pick : "))
    guess2 = int(input("Enter your second lottery pick : "))
    print("The lottery numbers are", lottery1, ',', lottery2)

    if guess2==lottery2 or guess1==lottery1:
        print("You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again")
    attempts-=1
    if (guess1 == lottery1 and guess2 == lottery2):
        guessed=True
        print("You got both numbers correct: you win $3,000")      
else:
    print("Sorry, no match")
```

## the output is as below:

```
Enter your first lottery pick : 35

Enter your second lottery pick : 45
The lottery numbers are 35 , 78
You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again
Sorry, no match

Enter your first lottery pick : 35
Enter your second lottery pick : 45
The lottery numbers are 35 , 45
You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again
You got both numbers correct: you win $3,000
Sorry, no match
```

I want to get rid of the line " You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again" when user guesses both numbers correctly and in the **second attempt** if user guesses one number correct.  I hope that makes sense

Comment: try to move `if guess2==lottery2 or guess1==lottery1` in an `elif` statement after `if (guess1 == lottery1 and guess2 == lottery2)`

Comment: Thatnks Vitalii. Doing that gets rid of " You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again" in case user guesses both numbers. It doesnt get rid of the line " You recieve $100!, and a chance to play again" if the guess is wrong the second time. I really appreciate your help though!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that indentation of the code snippet you have here is the same you have in your IDE. As you can see your else statement is not indented correctly. So first you have to check how many matches do you have, I would suggest you to use a list of your lottery numbers and then check against user guesses to see how many matches, this way your code will be more flexible. If both numbers matches, if not test if at least one matches, if none of them show them the `Sorry, no match` message.
So the code should look like :

```
matches = 0
lottery = [random.randint(0, 99), random.randint(45,109)]
guesses = [guess1, guess2]
for guess in guesses:
    if guess in lottery:
        matches+=1
# so now we know how many matches we have
# matches might be more than length of numbers in case you have the the  same numbers in lottery
if matches >= len(lottery):
    guessed=True
    print("You got both numbers correct: you win $3,000")
elif matches == 1:
    print("You receive $100!, and a chance to play again")
else:
    print("Sorry, no match")
    attempts-=1
```

Hope it was helpful!